# NewRelic configuration in Mendix private cloud

Tags: newrelic, javaagents, mendix

Can anyone provide the location of m2ee.yaml file for configuring Newrelic in mendix private cloud.

Ref URL: https://docs.mendix.com/developerportal/deploy/setting-up-monitoring-with-new-relic/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, the m2ee program tries to load configuration from the locations

## /etc/m2ee/m2ee.yaml and ~/.m2ee/m2ee.yaml

Comment: From where we can find m2ee.yaml file. Is this available in the Teamserver or somewhere else? 
Also How the data is pushed to newrelic from Mendix private cloud application?
Can you provide step by step guide for the same?